# I want to show one form data to another form using Laravel 5.8, Here i can use laravel collection packages

Tags: php, laravel, forms, multi-step

I want to show 1st form received data to 2nd form. How can i apply this process using laravel 5.8.
Also here i can use laravel collection packages.

```
/* ========= Routes ===========*/
Route::post('/subscribe/new', 'SubscriptionController@subscribeNew'); /1st form
Route::post('/subscribe/add', 'SubscriptionController@subscribeAdd'); /2nd form

/* ========== 1st Form ============ */
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'subscribe/new', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
     <input type="hidden" value="200" name="amount">
     <input type="hidden" value="1 Month" name="period">
     <input type="hidden" value="Basic" name="packageName">
     <input type="submit" name="btn" class="default-btn" value="Subscribe Now">
{!! Form::close() !!}

/* ========== subscribeNew Function ============ */
public function subscribeNew(Request $request){

        $amount = $request->input('amount');
        $period = $request->input('period');
        $packageName = $request->input('packageName');

        return redirect('/subscribe-form')
           ->with('amount', $amount)
           ->with('period', $period)
           ->with('packageName', $packageName);
    }

/* ========== 2nd Form , Here i want to show my 1st form value ============ */

{!! Form::open(['url' => '/subscribe/add', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
     <input type="text" name="packageName" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ ? }}">
     <input type="text" name="period" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ ? }}">                          
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" readonly value="{{ ? }}">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: In 2nd Form just use the variable name in value just like value="{{$amount}}"

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment, i can use this system. but show me a error, Undefined variable: packageName (View: D:\wamp64\www\xyzcompany\resources\views\frontEnd\subscribe\subscribeContent.blade.php)

Comment: `return redirect('/subscribe-form')` this won't work..you can just return your view..why a redirect??

Comment: You have to get all the variables from DB in controller and pass them in the view.

Comment: @KaleemShoukat i can solved this issue. Thank you..
i just use view.. remove "return redirect"

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thank you so much brother. I can use `view` then it will work properly.